# cakephp flash error at Undefined variable: _SESSION [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 440]

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am following Article example from internet. Here is my Article Controller

namespace App\Controller;

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
    }

    public function index() {
        $articles = $this->Articles->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }

    public function view($id) {
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('article'));
    }

    public function add() {
        $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
        }
        $this->set('article', $article);
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }

        $this->set('article', $article);
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        if ($this->Articles->delete($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The article with id: {0} has been deleted.', h($id)));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
    }

}
```

when I save form I am getting below errors

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: _SESSION [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 440]
Code Context
$name = 'Flash.flash'
$value = [
    'message' => 'Your article has been saved.',
    'key' => 'flash',
    'element' => 'Flash/success',
    'params' => []
]
$write = [
    'Flash.flash' => [
        'message' => 'Your article has been saved.',
        'key' => 'flash',
        'element' => 'Flash/success',
        'params' => []
    ]
]
Cake\Network\Session::write() - CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 440
Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent::set() - CORE/src/Controller/Component/FlashComponent.php, line 99
Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent::__call() - CORE/src/Controller/Component/FlashComponent.php, line 139
Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent::success() - APP/Controller/ArticlesController.php, line 22
App\Controller\ArticlesController::add() - APP/Controller/ArticlesController.php, line 22
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 411
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

line 22 is `$this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));`

Please note - I am just learning the basics and new to cakephp

Comment: you need to add session helper in your controller. Try `public $helpers = array('Session');` just before `index()` function.

Comment: Hello @anantkumarsingh I tried, still same error!

Comment: Sorry my mistake try `var $components =  array('Session');` and then write like `$this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added');`.Please try once.

Comment: I am using cakephp 3.0. I recheck the example and found that I was missing a method `public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
    }`
but after adding this still getting same error.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Your code is for CakePHP 1.x/2.x, CakePHP 3 no longer has the `$components` property, or a `Session` component. What @sunny is doing is correct for CakePHP 3.

Comment: ya i know what you said, but after @sunny comment i come to know he is using cakephp 3.0

Comment: I solved the problem by putting start_session(); in AppController.php