# Redirect to a homepage cakephp 3

Tags: php, redirect, routes, cakephp-3.0

I've followed the articles tutorial from cakephp 3 website and created the website

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV5ol.png

Now there is add article, delete article and edit article actions.

When I delete an article it redirect me to

http://localhost:8888/test/articles/delete/14

Here is the delete code.

```
public function delete($id) {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        if ($this->Articles->delete($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The article with id: {0} has been deleted.', h($id)));    
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
    }
```

The same is happening for add and edit.

Now it stays on the that blank page(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3ukg.png).  But `return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);` line suppose to redirect it to homepage i.e on index

In routes.php I've defined route as

```
 Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index'));
```

My question is, How can I redirect it to homepage. I followed the tutorial exactly as on the website.

Comment: there is a good chance that the delete does not happen. Try to add an `else` for your `if` and debug why you get there. Anyway if you switch debug on you will se what happens.
On the other hand `$this->redirect('/')` will redirect you to home.

Comment: @rrd Item is getting deleted. I tried ` $this->redirect('/') ` but same result.

Comment: @summea sure. Here it is http://pastebin.com/1gT6Fj9p

Comment: It was by mistake while pasting. on original file it is not there. Netbeans gives error if put / on line 54.

Comment: `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index'));` should be `$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index']);` in your file

Comment: I tried it but it s not working (:

Comment: @Sunny I think it might be time to try out `Debug Kit` to see what is happening when you add/edit/delete articles. Information about how to get started with [`Debug Kit` can be found here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html).

Comment: @summea Thanks I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Sunny, show us the whole php file containing the function `public function delete($id)` there is a good chance you actually are outputting what should be php comments from Netbeans (the licence header as a matter of facts).

Comment: @b.enoit.be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896248/cakephp-flash-error-at-undefined-variable-session-core-src-network-session-ph

Comment: @Sunny Ok then, this is not the one if you did paste it there in full and that you did not changed anything. What about your `webroot/index.php` and `webroot/test.php`. Also, what come up if you try to search **change this license header** in your whole project ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be I just did what you said and It works. Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that "license header" line is supposed to be a comment, but is not within `<?php ?>` tags and hence is being taken as output. If that's the case, the fact that some output has been generated already will stop the redirect from happening.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify controller name in controller attribute and action name in action attribute.

```
 $this->redirect(['Controller' => 'Homepage Controller name' , 'action' => 'homepafe action name']);
```

after succession it will redirect to your mentioned location.